# Aspnetcore healthchecks degraded status ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, health-check

I was learing about HealthChecks following the information posted on the MSDN site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-5.0#register-health-check-services

The following code snippet tells that if an unhealthy checks returns I can overwrite the value by saying it's degraded instead.

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddCheck<ExampleHealthCheck>(
        "example_health_check",
        failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded,
        tags: new[] { "example" });
```

So I tried this with this implementation, assuming that I would get a degraded result instead of an unhealthy one:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck<ExampleHealthCheck>("ExampleHealthCheck", failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded);
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
        });
    }
}
internal class ExampleHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
{
    public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("An unhealthy result."));
    }
}
```

Can someone shed some light on why this isn't working or where I got it wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to change the `ExampleHealthCheck`'s `CheckHealthAsync`'s  return value? So, instead of returning `Unhealthy` what if your code returns with for example `Healthy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite confusing, because you expect that the HealthCheck gives you back automatically the result you defined on the `failureStatus` property, but your HealthCheck explicitly returns `Unhealthy`.

If you take a look at the `AddHealthCheck<T>` method on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/HealthChecks/HealthChecks/src/DependencyInjection/HealthChecksBuilderAddCheckExtensions.cs), you will see in only creates an instance of `HealthCheckRegistration`.

```
public static IHealthChecksBuilder AddCheck(
            this IHealthChecksBuilder builder,
            string name,
            IHealthCheck instance,
            HealthStatus? failureStatus = null,
            IEnumerable<string>? tags = null,
            TimeSpan? timeout = null)
        {
            if (builder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
            }

            if (name == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            }

            if (instance == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(instance));
            }

            return builder.Add(new HealthCheckRegistration(name, instance, failureStatus, tags, timeout));
        }
```

This object is afterwards passed inside the context of your health check. You can then read the failureStatus which is expected in case of failure and then return an `HealthCheckResult` from it. In your case, this would return `Degraded` :

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck<ExampleHealthCheck>("ExampleHealthCheck", failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded);
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
        });
    }
}

internal class ExampleHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
{
   public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
   {
      return Task.FromResult(new HealthCheckResult(context.Registration.FailureStatus));
   }
}
```